# jQuery toggle with divs hierarchy

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

I'm working on tasks list with "hierarchy" *(see example below)*:

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="element">
        Element #1
    </div>

    <div class="elements">
        <div class="holder">
            <div class="element">
                Element #2
            </div>

            <div class="elements">
                <div class="holder">
                    <div class="element">
                        Element #3
                    </div>

                    <div class="elements">
                         <!-- empty -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With following `jQuery` code:

```
$('div.element').click(function(){

    $(this)
    .closest('div.holder')
    .find('div.elements')
    .eq(0)
    .toggle();
});
```

**Question:**

It's opening and closing `div.elements` as it supposed to, but for example if I'm opening all `div's`, and closing `Element #1` `div` - I want to close every other `div.elements` inside clicked `div.holder`.

Adding [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCyeQ/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCyeQ/13/)

Check this snippet,

You need to hide the child elements too, with the parent element click.

```
$('div.element').click(function () {

    $(this)
        .closest('div.holder')
        .find('div.elements')
        .eq(0)
        .toggle('fast',function () {
           $(this).find('div.elements').hide()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.element').click(function(){

    $('div.elements').hide();

    $(this)
    .closest('div.holder')
    .find('div.elements')
    .show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I needed. It's opening all `div.elements`, while I need to open one (first one) per `click`.